# Can not save page in https://archive.org/web/

Tags: https

I know that the page should be accessible and open for indexing. I have some pages with problem of saving in web archive. Most of them have the https protocol. For example, page https://www.asterra.ru/

Why do I get an response "Bummer.This url is not available on the live web or can not be archived."?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on https://archive.org/web/ in "Save Page Now" block:

> Only available for sites that allow crawlers.

Your [robots.txt](https://www.asterra.ru/robots.txt) blocks webarchive crawler so it can't create snapshot of your site.

Comment: What do you mean? Page https://www.asterra.ru/ not disallowed in robots.txt

Comment: I can't save page https://www.asterra.ru/robots.txt  in web archive too. It allow in robots.txt and does not contain files, which disallowed in robots.txt

Comment: Remove robots.txt and try to save page without it on site.

Comment: I don't have access to files of  asterra.ru, but i did it in site https://www.betonproject.ru/. It does not works. + As I know, archive.org ignores robots.txt content now.

Comment: If so, you mast check access log on your site to see what requests come to you site from archive.org and what responses are sent on them.